# Parsing a reserved word in Parsing Expressive Grammar (PEG.js)

Tags: parsing, peg

The [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933788/excluding-certain-elements-from-a-specified-set-in-parsing-expressive-grammar-p) and the [author's website](https://github.com/dmajda/pegjs/blob/master/examples/javascript.pegjs) give me solutions like this:

```
Identifier "identifier"
  = !ReservedWord [A-Za-z_]+

ReservedWord
  = "test"
  / "abc"
```

This solution can't parse an identifier like this "test_var".

In this example, the grammar !ReservedWord will exclusive all variables starting with "test" or "abc".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ReservedWord` succeeds, when a reserved word is complete, regardless of what follows. So the solution is to make it fail when there is a longer match that includes more identifier characters:

```
Identifier "identifier"
  = !ReservedWord [A-Za-z_]+

ReservedWord
  = ( "test" / "abc" ) ![A-Za-z_]
```

Comment: Nice solution. It helps me a lot.

Comment: Isn't that terribly inefficient?